# Android - call a method in a service from its parent

Tags: android, methods, service, call, parent

It sounds simple but I couldn't figure it out.. Is there a way to call a method in a service I started from it's parent? (Without using broadcast).

Comment: parent = the class that called `startService`?

Comment: why you dont want to use `broadcast`?

Comment: yes, I meant the class called startService

Answer (score 1):

Read about [bound services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). It allows you to create an interface between your activity and a service and call service method via that interface.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look